# Python sys.meta_path[1] the frozen importer. Does an application ever use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, contextmanager

I've gone fairly deep into --import--(), sys.meta_path[], and sys.path_hooks[]

In fact I'm writing an importer context manager to manage relative imports.

In standard Python (to 3.10) there are 3 meta_paths as listed below. Of course the intention is you can write your own meta_path finders and append them to sys.meta_path which I do.

Incidentally an entry in sys.meta_path should implement a method find_spec() which returns an 'import specification' which can easily be turned into a module

```
>>> sys.meta_path
[<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, <class 
'_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>, <class '_frozen_importlib_external.PathFinder'>]
```

0 the 'BuiltinImporter' gets you builtin modules like sys and math which are of course not implemented in Python but are part of the VM.

2 the 'PathFinder' gets stuff from sys.path both library stuff (os, re, enum) from e.g. '/usr/lib/python3.10'

2 gets your application imports.

Incidentally meta_path[2] uses sys.path_hooks[1] to get a finder for your application imports, but seems to need no help in getting library imports. Unless you're importing directly from a zip library in which case I guess sys.path_hooks[0] the zip finder is finally used.

1 the 'FrozenImporter' is clearly part of the import bootstrap.

The import mechanism itself is implemented in Python, so there's definitely a chicken and egg. I'm guessing the VM somehow uses it to make importing possible. Frozen means it's precompiled into .pyc and I also read that if the frozen files are somehow missing importlib can be bootstrapped from Python source which is slower.

By decorating '--import--()', 'sys.meta_path', and 'sys.path_hooks' I can see their interaction.

But sys.meta_path[1] the 'FrozenImporter' never seems to do anything. If I import 'importlib' no meta_path(s) run because importlib is already in sys.modules

If I examine 'os', and 'importlib' in sys.modules I can see they both came in with the same loader.

```
>>> import os
>>> type(sys.modules['os'].__spec__.loader)
<class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'>
>>> type(sys.modules['importlib'].__spec__.loader)
<class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'>
```

Ok my question is there any way an application can use sys.meta_path[1]?

I want to know to make sure my import shim supports that use case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've managed to make meta_path[1] fire

```
del sys.modules['_frozen_importlib']
del sys.modules['importlib']
import importlib
```

which through all my decorators produced the following excerpt:

```
pre  __import__("_frozen_importlib") mod: "importlib" fl: None level: "0" path: "['/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib']"
pre  meta_path[0] arg0 "_frozen_importlib"
post meta_path[0] arg0 "_frozen_importlib" result "None"
pre  meta_path[1] arg0 "_frozen_importlib"
post meta_path[1] arg0 "_frozen_importlib" result "ModuleSpec(name='_frozen_importlib', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>, origin='frozen')"
post __import__("_frozen_importlib") mod: "importlib" fl: None level: "0" path: "['/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib']" result: "<module '_frozen_importlib' (frozen)>"
```

The second last line above shows meta_path[1] returning a spec for _frozen_importlib.

Finishing with --import-- completing for importlib importing _frozen_importlib

Just in case anyone is interested it all starts with

```
pre  __import__("importlib") mod: "__main__" fl: None level: "0" path: ""
pre  meta_path[0] arg0 "importlib"
post meta_path[0] arg0 "importlib" result "None"
pre  meta_path[1] arg0 "importlib"
post meta_path[1] arg0 "importlib" result "None"
pre  meta_path[2] arg0 "importlib"
pre  path_hook[0] arg0 "/proj/software/shareware"
ex   path_hook[0] arg0 "/proj/software/shareware" ex "<class 'zipimport.ZipImportError'>" "not a Zip file"
post path_hook[0] arg0 "/proj/software/shareware" result "None"
pre  path_hook[1] arg0 "/proj/software/shareware"
post path_hook[1] arg0 "/proj/software/shareware" result "FileFinder('/proj/software/shareware')"
post meta_path[2] arg0 "importlib" result "ModuleSpec(name='importlib', loader=<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f2b72667640>, origin='/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib'])"
```

Showing meta_path[2] using path_hook[1] to find 'importlib'

Comment: You may be interested in [CPython's `Tools/build/freeze_modules.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Tools/build/freeze_modules.py) to see how to create custom frozen modules (like an Hello World), then use the `FrozenImporter` on it.